# Qual a diferença entre Train Test Split e Holdout?

Tags: python, pandas, sklearn

Pelo que já pesquisei, ambos dividem o conjunto em dois subconjuntos de treino e teste. Há alguma diferença entre os dois?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não. Hold out é literalmente "Esconder" parte do dataset, o que fazemos no sklearn ou bibliotecas similares usando `train_test_split`. Os termos são intercambiáveis.

Dê uma olhada no uso do termo na [documentação de validação cruzada do SKLearn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html).